# what is the difference between Flatten() and GlobalAveragePooling2D() in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I want to pass the output of ConvLSTM and Conv2D to a Dense Layer in Keras, what is the difference between using global average pooling and flatten
Both is working in my case.

```python
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=256,kernel_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Flatten())
# or model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

That both seem to work doesn't mean they do the same.

Flatten will take a tensor of any shape and transform it into a one dimensional tensor (plus the samples dimension) but keeping all values in the tensor. For example a tensor (samples, 10, 20, 1) will be flattened to (samples, 10 * 20 * 1).

GlobalAveragePooling2D does something different. It applies average pooling on the spatial dimensions until each spatial dimension is one, and leaves other dimensions unchanged. In this case values are not kept as they are averaged. For example a tensor (samples, 10, 20, 1) would be output as (samples, 1, 1, 1), assuming the 2nd and 3rd dimensions were spatial (channels last).

Comment: @NicolasGervais Actually no,  its more complicated, my answer is based on Keras from 2018, your answer is based in tf.keras (from 2020 I would guess), they behave differently. That does not make my answer wrong.

Comment: @NicolasGervais If you use keras around version 2.0 you will see it actually outputs (n, 1, 1, c). They changed it in later versions.

Comment: @NicolasGervais Its not wrong neither outdated, I have always said here in SO that keras and tf.keras are actually different libraries with different behavior.

Comment: Keras as a standalone python package is [largely abandoned](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.4.0) since Sep 2019.

Comment: @NicolasGervais So what? People are still using it. And there is already an answer here in the case for tf.keras, your answer does not add anything new.

Comment: @NicolasGervais Also note that this question is tagged as [keras], and from the tag description:  If you are using tensorflow's built-in keras, use the [tf.keras] tag

Answer (score 31):

### What a Flatten layer does

After convolutional operations, [`tf.keras.layers.Flatten`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Flatten) will reshape a tensor into `(n_samples, height*width*channels)`, for example turning `(16, 28, 28, 3)` into `(16, 2352)`. Let's try it:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.uniform(shape=(100, 28, 28, 3), minval=0, maxval=256, dtype=tf.int32)

flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()

flat(x).shape
```

```
TensorShape([100, 2352])
```

### What a GlobalAveragePooling layer does

After convolutional operations, [`tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GlobalAveragePooling2D) layer does is average all the values *according to the last axis*. This means that the resulting shape will be `(n_samples, last_axis)`. For instance, if your last convolutional layer had 64 filters, it would turn `(16, 7, 7, 64)` into `(16, 64)`. Let's make the test, after a few convolutional operations:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.cast(
    tf.random.uniform(shape=(16, 28, 28, 3), minval=0, maxval=256, dtype=tf.int32),
    tf.float32)


gap = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()

for i in range(5):
    conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3)
    x = conv(x)
    print(x.shape)

print(gap(x).shape)
```

```
(16, 24, 24, 64)
(16, 22, 22, 64)
(16, 20, 20, 64)
(16, 18, 18, 64)
(16, 16, 16, 64)

(16, 64)
```

### Which should you use?

The `Flatten` layer will always have at least as much parameters as the `GlobalAveragePooling2D` layer. If the final tensor shape before flattening is still large, for instance `(16, 240, 240, 128)`, using `Flatten` will make an insane amount of parameters: `240*240*128 = 7,372,800`. This huge number will be multiplied by the number of units in your next dense layer! At that moment, `GlobalAveragePooling2D` might be preferred in most cases. If you used `MaxPooling2D` and `Conv2D` so much that your tensor shape before flattening is like `(16, 1, 1, 128)`, it won't make a difference. If you're overfitting, you might want to try `GlobalAveragePooling2D`.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the intermediate outputs would be different. I checked and indeed. I get: (16, 26, 26, 64), (16, 24, 24, 64), (16, 22, 22, 64), (16, 20, 20, 64), (16, 18, 18, 64).

Answer (score 10):

Flattening is No brainer and it simply converts a multi-dimensional object to one-dimensional by re-arranging the elements.

While GlobalAveragePooling is a methodology used for better representation of your vector. It can be 1D/2D/3D. It uses a parser window which moves across the object and pools the data by averaging it (GlobalAveragePooling) or picking max value (GlobalMaxPooling). Padding is essentially required to take the corner cases into the account.

Both are used for taking effect of sequencing into account in a simpler way.

Answer (score 9):

You can test **the difference between Flatten and GlobalPooling** on your own making comparison with numpy, if you are more confident

We make a demonstration using, as input, a batch of images with this shape `(batch_dim, height, width, n_channel)`

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

batch_dim, H, W, n_channels = 32, 5, 5, 3
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (batch_dim,H,W,n_channels)).astype('float32')
```

- `Flatten` accepts as input tensor of at least 3D. It operates a reshape of the input in 2D with this format `(batch_dim, all the rest)`. In our case of 4D, it operates a reshape in this format `(batch_dim, H*W*n_channels)`.

  ```
  np_flatten = X.reshape(batch_dim, -1) # (batch_dim, H*W*n_channels)
  tf_flatten = Flatten()(X).numpy() # (batch_dim, H*W*n_channels)

  (tf_flatten == np_flatten).all() # True
  ```
- `GlobalAveragePooling2D` accepts as input 4D tensor. It operates the mean on the height and width dimensionalities for all the channels. The resulting dimensionality is 2D `(batch_dim, n_channels)`. `GlobalMaxPooling2D` makes the same but with max operation.

  ```
  np_GlobalAvgPool2D = X.mean(axis=(1,2)) # (batch_dim, n_channels)
  tf_GlobalAvgPool2D = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(X).numpy() # (batch_dim, n_channels)

  (tf_GlobalAvgPool2D == np_GlobalAvgPool2D).all() # True
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Compression ratio of parameters is exponentially high in **Global Average Pooling**,**Flatten** just reshape the matrix to one dimension, both can be fed to Fully connected networks
Thanks