# Passing arguments to function after parenthesis

Tags: python, function, tensorflow, call

I have problem in understanding this code in Python

```
x = layers.Flatten()(last_output)
```

Since Flatten is a function, how does the function get the data from last_output written outside the function call parenthesis. Don't remember seeing this kind of code in Java.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176982/how-does-the-flatten-layer-work-in-keras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatten() is the class instantiation (which is probably clear to you) and the second calls the instance with that parameter. For this to work the class must have a `__call__` function defined.

Example:

```
class Sum:
    def __call__(self, a, b, c):
        return a + b + c

s = Sum()
print(s(3, 4, 5))
print(Sum()(3,4,5))
```

Also same behavior can be obtained with a function that returns another function with arguments:

```
def Sum2():
    def Sum3(a, b, c):
        return a + b + c
    return Sum3

s2 = Sum2()
print(s2(3, 4, 5))
print(Sum2()(3, 4, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this

```
def outer():
    def print_thrice(string):
          for _ in range(3):
              print (string)
    return print_thrice
```

If you call `outer`, it will return the `print_thrice` function which you can then call. So you'd use it like this

```
x = outer()
x("hello")
```

Or more compactly, `outer()("hello")` which is what's going on here.